# Cocoapods iOS - [!] Google has been deprecated - How to get rid of the warning?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

**Steps I did:**

1. `pod repo remove master`
2. `pod setup`
3. `pod update --verbose` (Just to check the progress especially when updating the Google SDKs, took so long to finish).

And there, I got the warning. In my logs, Google SDKs were updated successfully:

> -> Installing Google 3.1.0 (was 3.0.3)
>
> -> Installing GoogleMaps 2.3.0 (was 2.2.0)

**Podfile:**

```
target 'MyProj' do

    ...
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    ...
    target 'MyProjTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
    end

    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

[image]

I would like to know how to get rid of this warning.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Change `pod 'Google/Analytics'` to `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` removing the slash.

Comment: Wow. Thank you, Paul! Thought it was the GoogleMaps causing this so I thought there was nothing wrong with my podfile.

Comment: I experienced some issues when switching from Google/Analytics to GoogleAnalytics concerning my Google-Service-info.plist and therefore I decided that I can cope better with a deprecation instead of updating a lot of code.

Comment: No need to change anything in your plsit file after updating your dependency (in this case, Google Analytics). Just some a bit of codes. But it's up to you, of course.

Comment: if you change from with-slash to without-slash, you have modify a lot of contents in the bridging header file, and probably in more other locations.

Comment: FYI: in case of `Google/SignIn` it will be `GoogleSignIn`

Comment: This is very helpful.  Good catch! Thank you for capturing it here.

Comment: Official doc from Google: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

Comment: It is not working for me. I have removed slash... but still it is there

Comment: @MehulThakkar Check the Podfile.lock to find out what is pulling in the deprecated `Google` pod.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien for reply. Actually i were making some other mistake. now it is working.

Answer (score 46):

Extending on Paul Beusterien answer:

First, remove old import from your bridging header:

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

Then, add the following to the bridging header instead:

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceFields.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProduct.h"
#import "GAIEcommerceProductAction.h"
#import "GAIEcommercePromotion.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAILogger.h"
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
```

Finally you might want to recheck:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

You don't need GGLContext line anymore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To those who are previously using the `google-info.plist` via GGLContext configuration, you must now explicitly specify your tracking id through code.

Comment: @Teffi Could you drop a reference to support that?

Comment: @LordZsolt It's already indicated on the reference posted above. I'm just only reiterating that prior to this new update you can let GGLContext read the tracker id from the plist thus omitting the need to add it programmatically but this time it isn't the case anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Also, I had to remove `import Google` from my swift files.