# Firebase error even if I don't use it

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, google-analytics, cocoapods

In my `objective-c` application, I added `Google Analytics` using `Pods` (this is how I add it: `pod 'Google/Analytics'`). In the `Pods` folder, I found those `Firebase` packages `FirebaseAnalytics`, `FirebaseCore` and the `FirebaseInstanceId`). When I run my application, sometimes it crash and this is what I'm getting in the console:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not
>   yet been configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application
>   initialization.

I don't call the Firebase classes anymore and I don't want to use them.

Why am I having `Firebase` even if I didn't add them? Why am I having this error? How can I resolve this? If I delete the packages will that cause a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Google` pod depends on Firebase.  Change your Podfile to directly depend upon `GoogleAnalytics` without the slash.

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics is **not** recommended [anymore](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) for mobile applications:

> The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track iOS apps.

And AFAIK, the development of the features + pod maintenance is not a priority as they fully shifted towards Firebase.

I know some legacy code has to remain on GA because of outstanding history of logs. But if you have a fresh app, I strongly recommend doing analytics with Firebase.

Comment: That's the problem. It isn't a fresh app. It was using the Google Analytics lib so I migrate it to Pods. If I disable Firebase, will that impact on the Google Analytics part?

Comment: @Llg for start, according to the tutorial I linked, try substituting `pod Google/Analytics` for `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'`. Maybe that'll make the problems go away and let you keep the old platform running.

Comment: As discussed in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538472/cocoapods-ios-google-has-been-deprecated-how-to-get-rid-of-the-warning